# AngularJS communication between Controller and Factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use AngularJS together with Cisco NeXt UI Toolkit, which is an HTML5/JavaScript based toolkit for network web applications (https://developer.cisco.com/site/NeXt-test/). The application logic should be done by AngularJS and NeXt should only draw the network maps.

I put all the NeXt related stuff into an AngularJS factory and access it on demand from the AngularJS controllers. The problem now is that NeXt builds some parts of the GUI by its own, including buttons and forms and I would like to communicate back from the Factory to the controller that a button was pressed or the data a user filled in to the form.

How can I do that or do I hve to use something different than a Factory?

Comment: Do you have code that you can provide to show what you are doing?

Comment: not familiar with Next but my first thought would be use angular events ($emit, $broadcast) within event handlers of Next components

Comment: You call use a call back, ie a function that you pass to the factory from the controller. When the factory needs to pass data to the controller it can call the function passing in any data required.

Comment: @daniellepelley: Passing the function as parameter to the Factory did the trick - Thank you very much!

Comment: @charlietfl: thank you for the answer, but I don't know if it is possible to use AngularJS events inside NeXt.